# Post open graph action using c# and HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, facebook, httpwebrequest

Hi all I am trying to post an open graph action to facebook using a HttpWebRequest method.

Here's my request method

```
public static string RequestUrl(string action, String HTTPMETHOD, dynamic postdata = null)
    {
        string results = "";

        try
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(action);
            if (HTTPMETHOD == "GET")
            {
                req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            }
            else if (HTTPMETHOD == "POST")
            {
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
                req.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
                byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postdata.sneaqer);
                req.ContentLength = data.Length;
                req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream();
                newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                newStream.Close();
            }
            else if (HTTPMETHOD == "DELETE")
            {
                req.Method = "DELETE";
                ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
            }
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            results = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error.Log("ERROR: Common.cs requestUrl() " + ex.Message + " " + action);
        }

        return results;
    }
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + personFacebookUserId + "/verbNamespace:follow";
    dynamic parameters = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
    parameters.person = "http:" + Configuration.getConfigValue("SiteUrl") + "OG/OpenGraphAction.aspx?type=follow&facebookProfilePicture=" + friendFacebookUserId;
    string result = Common.RequestUrl(url, "POST", parameters);
```

I get an error server returned a bad request. I think the problem is the way I am passing in the parameters. The person is the object and follow is the action.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this guys article very useful [Using ASP.Net with Facebook’s Graph API and OAuth 2.0 Authentication](http://osnapz.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/using-asp-net-with-facebooks-graph-api-and-oauth-2-0-authentication/) Seems you have to get a auth token by having them redirect to one of your pages.